# Fourier transform of the derivative - insufficient hypotheses?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

An exercise in Carlos ISNARD's *Introdução à medida e integração*:

> Show that if $f$ and $f'$ $\in\mathscr{L}^1(\mathbb{R},\lambda,\mathbb{C})$ and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=0$ then $\hat{(f')}(\zeta)=i\zeta\hat{f}(\zeta)$.

($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.)

I'm tempted to apply integration by parts on the integral from $-N$ to $N$ and then take limit as $N\to\infty$. But to obtain the result I seemingly need $f'e^{-i\zeta x}$ to be Riemann-integrable so as to use the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a measure-theoretic version of the fundamental theorem of Calculus, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Calculus#Generalizations).

Comment: Thank you. The thing is, up to that point in the textbook no such theorem has been mentioned, so that's why I'm wondering.

Answer (score 3):

We can find a sequence of $C^1$ functions with compact support $\{f_j\}$ such that $$\lVert f-f_j\rVert_{L^1}+\lVert f'-f_j'\rVert_{L^1}\leq \frac 1j.$$
This is a standard result about Sobolev spaces. Actually more is true: the smooth functions with compact support are dense in $W^{1,1}(\Bbb R)$, but that's not needed here. It's theorem 13 in [Willie Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1543/willie-wong)'s [notes about Sobolev spaces](https://documents.epfl.ch/users/w/ww/wwywong/www/lecturenotes/NotesOnSobolevSpaces.pdf).

Convergence in $L^1$ shows that for all $\xi$ we have $\widehat{f_j}(\xi)\to \widehat{f}(\xi)$ and $\widehat{f_j'}(\xi)\to \widehat{f'}(\xi)$. And the result for $C^1$ functions follows as stated in the OP by integration by parts.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to Willie's notes?

Comment: Actually I download them a long time ago, and I don't remember the link. @WillieWong: could you edit my answer including a link to your notes about Sobolev spaces? Thanks!

Comment: I see. Thanks. ${}$