# Derivative of convolution

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Assume that $f(x),g(x)$ are positive and are in $L^1$. Moreover, they are differentiable and their derivative is integrable. Let $h(x)=f(x)*g(x)$, the convolution of $f$ and $g$. Does the derivative of $h(x)$ exist? If yes, how can we prove that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)*g(x)) = \left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)*g(x)$$

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate under the integral sign?

Comment: This can be helpful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/will-moving-differentiation-from-inside-to-outside-an-integral-change-the-resu

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if _either_ $f$ or $g$ is differentiable, then $f*g$ is differentiable.  If $f$ is differentiable, then $(f*g)'=f'*g$.  If they're both differentiable then $(f*g)'=f'*g=f*g'$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Sorry to revive this old comment, I arrived at it following some links to recent questions. I think that what you say is not true if $'$ stands for a classical derivative. To obtain such a result you need the dominated convergence theorem, which is available only with some additional assumption (for example, $f'\in L^\infty$ will do). However, the result is certainly true if $'$ stands for derivative in some other sense, such as a Fourier multiplier or something like that. Do you agree?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : Maybe I was hasty; I was just assuming everything was well-behaved except in the respects mentioned.

Comment: Can anyone expand more on these assumptions? "Assume that (),() are positive and are in 1."

Answer (score 36):

Using [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176831/fourier-transform-of-the-derivative-insufficient-hypotheses/176869#176869), and the fact that if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two integrable functions, $\mathcal F(f\star g)=\mathcal F(f)\cdot\mathcal F(g)$, we have 
$$\mathcal F\left(\frac d{dx}(f\star g)\right)(x)=ix\mathcal F\left((f\star g)\right)(x)=ix \mathcal F(f)(x)\cdot \mathcal F(g)(x),$$
and 
$$\mathcal F\left(\left(\frac d{dx}f\right)\star g\right)(x)=\left(\mathcal F\left(\frac d{dx}f\right)\right)\cdot\left(\mathcal F(g)(x)\right)=ix \mathcal F(f)(x)\cdot \mathcal F(g)(x).$$
We conclude by uniqueness of Fourier transform.

Comment: How you can take Fourier transform while we don't know it has Fourier transform or not? In other words, we don't know $\frac{d}{dx} (f*g)$ is in $L^1$? For the second Fourier transform, it is correct since we know that $f'*g$ is in $L^1$.

Comment: Indeed, it deserves more details. I think an approximation argument can work (approximate in $L^1$ $f$ and $g$ by $C^1$ functions with compact support).

Answer (score 28):

Definition: $$h(x)=f*g(x)=\int_A f(x-t)g(t)dt$$ where A is a support of function $q()$, i.e. $A=\{t:q(t)\ne 0\}$

Let's calculate derivative:

$$\frac {dh}{dx}=\underset{dx\rightarrow0}{\lim} \frac {(\int_A f(x+dx-t)g(t)dt-\int_A f(x-t)g(t)dt)}{dx}=\underset{dx\rightarrow0}{\lim}(\int_A \frac{(f(x+dx-t)-f(x-t))}{dx}g(t)dt)$$

If we assume that there exists some integrable function $q(t)$, such that for $t$ almost everywhere
$$
\left| \frac{(f(x+dx-t)-f(x-t))}{dx} \right| < q(t), \forall dx>0
$$

I.e.
$$
\mu\{t: \left| \frac{(f(x+dx-t)-f(x-t))}{dx} \right| \ge q(t)\}=0,\forall dx >0
$$

then by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem we can push the limit inside integral.

$$\frac {dh}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(f*g(x))=\int_A f'(x-t)g(t)dt=f'*g$$

Under assumption that: $\int_A q(t)dt$ is bounded above.
One situation is when A is a compact set and $f,g$ are continuous function in the set A with a finite number of dicontinuities.

Answer (score 15):

Note that, if $ f\in L_1(R)$ then it is Fourier transformable. Since,

$$ \left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-ixw}\right|  \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)| < \infty$$.

To prove that the convolution of two $L_{1}(R)$ functions is again an $L_{1}(R)$ function, let

$$ h(x) = \int f(t) g(x-t) dt $$

$$ \int |h(x)|dx \leq \int\int |f(t)| |g(x-t)| dt dx = \int |f(t)|\int |g(x-t)|dxdt = \int |f(t)| ||g||_1 dt = ||f||_1 ||g||_1 \Rightarrow h \in L_1(R)\,.$$

The change of the order of integration is justified by Fubini's theorem. So, you can use the Fourier technique as in Davide's answer.

Comment: Why should $\frac{d(f*g)(x)}{dx}$ be Fourier transformable?

Answer (score 0):

In the case there your functions are only defined on $[0,\infty)$, you get the following.

Given $f, g: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^n$, define the convolution
$$
(f*g)(t) = \int_{\tau  = 0}^t f(t)g(t-\tau)d\tau  = \int_{\tau  = 0}^t f(t-\tau)g(t)d\tau  .
$$

Let $f, g \in L_2([0,\infty))$ be differentiable, and suppose $\dot{g}\in L_2([0,t_0])$ for any $t_0>0.$ Setting $p = (f*g),$ we have
$$\dot{p}(t) = (f*\dot{g})(t) + f(t) g(0).
$$

To prove this, write
\begin{align*}
\dot{p}(t) & = \lim_{h\to 0} h^{-1}\left[ \int_0^{t+h} f(u) g(t+h-u) du - \int_0^t f(u) g(t-u)du\right] \\
    & = \lim_{h\to 0 }  \int_0^{t+h} f(u) \frac{g(t+h-u)-g(t-u)}{h} du +  \int_t^{t+h} \frac{f(u) g(t-u)}{h} du\\
    & = (f*\dot{g})(t) + f(t)g(0),
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows for the first integral by writing the integrand with the mean value theorem as
$f(u) \chi_{[0, t+h]}(u) \dot{g}(\xi)$ for $\xi \in (t-u, t+h-u)$ or
$(t-u, t+h-u)$ and applying Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, and for the second integral by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Using Leibniz integral rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(f*g(x)\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(g(t)f(x-t))dt} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(t){\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-t)dt}=g*\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f$$