# Under What Conditions and Why can Move Operator under Integral?

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a function space $V$ of some subset of real-valued functions on the real line, linear operator $L: V \rightarrow  V$, and  $f,g \in V$, define
$$ h(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(u)g(u-t)du  $$

Further, assume $h \in V$.  Is the below true?  $$L(h(t)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(u)L(g(u-t))du $$ If not, under what assumptions is this true? If yes, why?

Comment: See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177239/derivative-of-convolution) it might be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arbitrary operator cannot be moved into the convolution. For example, if $Lh=\psi h$ for some nonconstant function $\psi$, then $$\psi(t) \int_{\mathbb R} f(u) g(u-t)  \,du \ne \int_{\mathbb R} f(u) g(u-t) \psi(u-t) \,du $$
for general $f,g$.

However, the identity is true for *translation-invariant* operators, i.e., those for which $L(g(t-c))=L(g)(t-c)$ for every $c\in\mathbb R$. Indeed, for such operators 
$$f*(Lg)= \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(u)L(g)(u-t)\,du =\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(u)L(g(u-t))\,du = L(f*g)$$