# Show that convolution of two measurable functions is well-defined

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Question**:

> Recall the definition of the convolution of $f$ and $g$ given by
>   $$(f*g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x-y)g(y)dy.$$ If  we only know that
>   $f$ and $g$ are measurable, can we show that $f*g$ is well defined for
>   a.e. $x$, that is, $f(x-y)g(y)$ is integrable?
>
> (Exercise 2.5.21(c) in 'Real Analysis', by Stein and Shakarchi)

Actually, the book writes like this:

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
>
> (a)Prove that $f(x-y)g(y)$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$.
>
> (b)Show that if $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$, then
>   $f(x-y)g(y)$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$.
>
> (c)Recall the definition of the convolution of $f$ and $g$ given by
>   $$(f*g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x-y)g(y)dy$$ Show that $f*g$ is well
>   defined for a.e. $x$, that is, $f(x-y)g(y)$ is integrable.

Can we use the assumption that $f,g$ are integrable in (c)?

Comment: No, we need some "smallness" condition, like that $f$ and $g$ are integrable (other conditions suffice too, $f$ integrable and $g \in L^p$ implies $f\ast g \in L^p$ for $1 \leqslant p \leqslant \infty$).

Comment: What if $f\equiv 1$ and $g$ is not integrable?

Comment: If $f$ is a distribution and $g$ is a smooth, compactly supported function, then $f*g$ is defined.

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177239/derivative-of-convolution).

Answer (score 5):

The assumption "$f$ and $g$ are integrable" appears in (b). I guess this is why the author (carelessly) omits it in (c). Without such assumption, e.g. $f=g=1$ on ${\bf R}^d$, the convolution might be nonsense.

If $f, g: {\bf R}^d \to {\bf C}$ are absolutely integrable, then by the [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/245a-notes-6-outer-measures-pre-measures-and-product-measures/), $f(y) g(x-y)$ is absolutely integrable on ${\bf R}^d \times {\bf R}^d$, which by further application of Fubini-Tonelli shows that $f(y) g(x-y)$ is absolutely integrable in $y$ for almost every $x$.

Comment: The note in the link has a clear explanation of the Tonelli Theorem, Fubini Theorem and the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem.

Comment: Sorry for being so dense, but I'm having a very tough time grasping how to apply the Fubini-Tonelli theorem. Could you please elaborate why F-T implies that $f(y)g(x -y)$ is absolutely integrable? Apparently I do not follow any application of F-T unless it's completely spelled out for me.

Comment: Nevermind, a detailed explanation is given here (on page 3): https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m127c/hmwk6_solutions.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Hint: do that first when $f, g \ge 0$. Recall that if the integrand function has a sign, you can safely change the order of integration in a double integral. This is sometimes known as *Tonelli's theorem*.

Tonelli's theorem is easier than the closely related Fubini's theorem, which regards integrand functions which possibly change sign. In the latter, you need to check that the integrand function is absolutely integrable with respect to both variables before you can do anything.

Comment: So you mean that $f$ and $g$ in (c) are integrable? I'm just not sure about this.

Comment: Yes, of course. If $f$ or $g$ are not absolutely integrable then there is no guarantee that their convolution product makes sense. There are easy counterexamples, see Landscape's and Daniel Fisher's comments above.