# Application of Fubini's theorem to prove that convolution is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

I guess that this is an easy question, but I don't have a very solid math background.

I'm trying to prove that if $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $h = f \star g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

So, I have:

$ h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)g(t-u)du$

Then I do:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(t)|dt &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)g(t-u)du\right|dt \\
&\leq& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(u)| |g(t-u)|du dt
\end{eqnarray*}

And here comes the question. I need to apply Fubini's theorem so I can change the order of integration. But to prove the conditions of applicability of Fubini's, I have to integrate with respect to $t$ first. This sounds circular to me and I can't find a way to do this that convinces me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Tonelli's theorem?

Comment: I didn't know it; I'm reading about it now. But the part about $\sigma$-finite measure spaces confuses me. How that relates to this situation?

Comment: Real spaces must be sigma-finite. Do not worry too much about that.

Comment: So, Wikipedia says:

_The conclusion of Tonelli's theorem is identical to that of Fubini's theorem, but the assumptions are different. Tonelli's theorem states that on the product of two σ-finite measure spaces, a product measure integral can be evaluated by way of an iterated integral for nonnegative measurable functions, regardless of whether they have finite integral._

I'm working with the product of two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces (namely, $\mathbb{R}^2$) and my functions are nonnegative (absolute values) and measurable. So I can change the order of integration for free?

Comment: Essentially, Yes.  Tonelli is very powerful.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers and your patience.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177239/derivative-of-convolution).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Fubini-Tonelli Theorem instead of Fubini's Theorem, which only requires that your integrant is non-negative, and has the same conclusion as ordinary Fubini's Theorem.

The statement of Fubini-Tonelli Theorem is:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to [0,\infty]$ be measurable, and $x\mapsto \int f_x\,d\lambda_2$ and $y\mapsto \int f^y\,d\lambda_1$ are Borel measurable. Then
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_1}}\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}}f_x\,d\lambda_2\bigg)\,d\lambda_1=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}}\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_1}}f^y\,d\lambda_1\bigg)\,d\lambda_2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_1+d_2}}f\,d\lambda.$$