# Show that the convolution of functions is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $2\pi$-periodic functions such that $f$ is bounded, $g$ is differentiable and $g'$ is continuous. How can I show that the convolution $g*f$ is differentiable?

I hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: See here - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177239/derivative-of-convolution

Comment: If these functions are periodic, how are you defining their convolution? In general it will be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fun way is using Fourier analysis. You need to know Parseval; that tells you that $$\sum |\hat f(n)|^2<\infty.$$And since $\widehat{g'}(n)=in\hat g(n)$, Parseval also tells you that $$\sum n^2|\hat g(n)|^2<0.$$Now Cauchy-Schwarz tells you that $$\sum|n||\hat f(n)\hat g(n)|<\infty,$$which implies that $f*g$ has a continuous derivative.

Ok, what if that's too much fun? You can do it directly. A hint is that the derivative of $f*g$ "should" be $f*(g')$. Write down the definition of $$\frac{f*g(x+h)-f*g(x)}{h}$$as an integral, write down the definition of $$f*(g')(x)$$as an integral, and see if you can show the first integral tends to the second integral as $h\to0$.

Hint for that: Since $g'$ is continuous (and periodic) it follows that $(g(x+h)-g(x))/h$ tends to $g'(x)$ *uniformly* as $h\to0$.

Comment: David, you had a minor typo which I corrected. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: What if I don't use Parseval? Can't I use definitions or any other simpler way? Thanks!

Comment: @CameronWilliams No problem, not even going to check what it was.

Comment: Ok, I'll add a big hint for a direct solution to my answer. Stay tuned

Comment: @David : sorry but I did not get the hint.

Comment: There are two ways to write any given convolution - sometimes $\int f(t)g(x-t)dt$ works and sometimes $\int f(x-t)g(t)$ works. Take your convolutions and try writing them the other way...

Comment: We get it yet? If not, show us what happened when you wrote out those convolutions as integrals...