# Prove $ \frac{d}{dt}(f *g)(t) = \int_0^tg(t-s)f^{'}(s)ds \; \; + f(0)g(t) $

Tags: integration, analysis, convolution

Given that $f,g$ are continuous real and differentiable functions on $[0,T]$ and

$$ (f*g)(t) := \int_0^tf(t-s)g(s)ds  $$

Prove that:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}(f *g)(t) = \int_0^tg(t-s)f^{'}(s)ds \; \; + f(0)g(t)   $$

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: I don't mean to be nit picky, but you'll need to at least assume that $f$ is differentiable; otherwise the right hand side doesn't make sense. What have you tried here?

Comment: By commutativity of convolution we would also have
$$
\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt}(f\star g)(t) =  \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt}(g\star f)(t) = \int_0^t f(t-s)g'(s)\ \mathsf ds + g(0)f(t),
$$
so we need to assume that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on $(0,T)$.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177239/derivative-of-convolution

Comment: @User8128, Ah yes, sorry I forgot about the differentiability, I'll fix that now.

Comment: @Masacroso    I looked around in books and online and found the Leibniz integral rule. I tried playing around with that, but it didn't get me the answer.

Comment: You might want to consider the convolution theorem and the relation between the derivative and its Fourier transform.