# Convolution of $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R^n})$ and $L^1_{loc}$ is $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R^n})$

Tags: continuity, convolution, differential

In [Terry's Tao blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/), Exercise $1$(ii),

> Show that if $f \in C^\infty_c({\bf R}^d)$ and $g: {\bf R}^d \rightarrow {\bf R}$ is absolutely integrable and compactly supported, then the convolution $f*g$ is also in $C^\infty_c({\bf R}^d)$. 
>   (Hint: first show that $f*g$ is continuously differentiable with $\nabla(f*g) = (\nabla f)*g$.

By definition of convolution, $(f * g)(x) = \int f(y)g(x-y) dy$. However, I have no idea how to show that it is continuously differentiable.

In the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177239/derivative-of-convolution) given by bruziuz, it is shown that for $f,g \in L^1$, we have $\nabla(f*g) = (\nabla f) * g$. Can we say the same to the above question?

Comment: If $f \in C^\infty_c$ and $g \in L^1$ then $|g \ast f(x+h)- g \ast f(x)| = |\int g(y) (f(x+h-y)-f(x-y)) dy| \le \|g\|_{L^1} \sup_x |f(x+h)-f(x)|$. Since $f'$ (or $\|\nabla f\|$) is bounded then $\sup_x |f(x+h)-f(x)| \le C|h|$ and $g \ast f$ is uniformly continuous. The same argument applies for showing  $g \ast f$ is uniformly $C^k$ for every $k$

Comment: If $g$ is only $L^1_{loc}$ then locally the same argument works again, since $f$ is compactly supported. A little more work and you get that $\partial_\alpha(f \ast g) =(\partial_\alpha f) \ast g$