# convolution of triangle function and sine

Tags: convolution, dirac-delta

I am interested in the convolution of a triangle function of width 2d with a cosine function (it has a useful analogy with a physics problem).

I think I should be able to break the problem down using the following:

- triangle function of width $2d$ is two convolved box-cars of width $d$
- a box-car is two Heaviside functions (one positive, one negative... I think)
- derivative of Heaviside function H: $\partial H = \delta$
- for any convolution $\partial f * g = f*\partial g$
- $\partial (f*g) = \partial f *\partial g$ (I think)
- $\delta*-\delta = 0$ (I think)

The general idea is to convert a triangle function into an equivalent set of convolved Heaviside functions with some offsets, then take the derivative and convolve a bunch of dirac delta functions with the sinusoid.

Therefore, for triangle function $T$, box-cars $B$:

$T(x)*\cos = T(x)*\partial(\sin(x))\\
= (B(x-d/2)*B(x+d/2))*\partial(\sin)\\
= ((H(x-d)-H(x))*(H(x)-H(x+d)))*\partial(\sin)\\
= \partial\big[(H(x-d)-H(x))*(H(x)-H(x+d))\big]*\sin\\
= \big[(\delta(x-d)-\delta(x))*(\delta(x)-\delta(x+d))\big]*\sin\\
= 0*\sin(x)$

Clearly, that is hilariously wrong. This convolution does not generally self-cancel.

I'm sure there is a nice analytical expression here, but I am not sure how to proceed.

PS. For future readers, the flaw is using $\partial (f*g) = \partial f *\partial g$.  Differentiation is not distributive across convolution.  Error thus propagates from line 4.

Comment: you can try variants of this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convolve(tri(x),+sin(x))

Comment: Of course Wolfram can do that... Inspired me to a correct derivation.  Will post it later.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a valid derivation.  Matches the numerical solution in MATLAB, although off by a constant scaling factor.

Taking a triangle from 0 to 2d.

$T(x)*\cos(x) = T(x)*\partial(\sin(x))\\
= \partial(T)*\sin(x)\\
= (B(d/2)-B(3d/2))*\sin(x)\\
= (B(d/2)-B(3d/2))*\partial(-\cos(x))\\
= \partial \big[ B(d/2)-B(3d/2) \big]*-\cos(x)\\
= \big[ \delta(x) - 2\delta(x-d) + \delta(x-2d) \big]*-\cos(x)\\
= -\cos(x) + 2 \cos(x - d) - \cos(x - 2d)$

Generalising to an input $A k\cos(kx)$ [weird I know, but that's my actual physics equation] I get the result

$T(x)*\cos = \frac{A}{k}\bigg(-\cos(x) + 2 \cos(x - d) - \cos(x - 2d)\bigg)$

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in your derivation. First, if $$B(x-d/2)=H(x)-H(x-d),$$ then $$B(x+d/2)=H(x+d)-H(x).$$ Second, $\partial(f*g)=\partial(f)*g$. On the other hand, in the second last step, you used $\partial(f*g) = \partial(f)*\partial(g)$. Correcting them might help.

Comment: Heaviside conversion had a typo. thanks! Those lines now agree with my final answer.  However, I did not state $\partial(f*g)=\partial(f)*g$, I stated $\partial(f*g)=\partial f*\partial g$, so I think that bit is okay, unless the derivative is not actually distributive.

Comment: @Mark_Anderson Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177239/derivative-of-convolution for the derivative of convolution.

Comment: Cool, so the derivative is not distributive across convolution. Thanks for the correction.