# Derivative of Convolution: A Contradiction

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution, inverse-laplace

Consider the differential equation
$$\dot{v}(t)+2\lambda v(t)=r(t) \tag{Eq. 1}$$
of a **causal** system with $$r(t) \not\equiv0$$

Using Laplace transform,
$$sV(s)-V_0+2\lambda V(s)=R(s)$$
where $V_0$ is the value of $v(t)$ at $t=0$.

$$V(s)=V_0(\frac{1}{s+2\lambda})+R(s)(\frac{1}{s+2\lambda})$$
Using inverse Laplace transform, the solution to the differntial equation is therefore
$$v(t)=V_0e^{-2\lambda t}+\int_{0}^{t}e^{-2\lambda (t-\tau)}r(\tau)d\tau$$
where
$v_h(t) = V_0e^{-2\lambda t}$ is the homogeneous solution and $v_p(t) = \int_{0}^{t}e^{-2\lambda (t-\tau)}r(\tau)d\tau$ is the particular solution. Note that both $v_h(t)$ and $v_p(t)$ satisfy Eq. 1.

We know that
$$ \frac{d}{dt}(f(t)*g(t)) = (\frac{d}{dt}f(t))*g(t) \tag{Eq.2}$$

If we let $f(t) = e^{-2\lambda (t-\tau)}$ and $g(t)=r(t)$, then $$\dot{v_p}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(f(t)*g(t))=(-2\lambda e^{-2 \lambda t})*r(t)=-2\lambda\int_{0}^{t}e^{-2\lambda (t-\tau)}r(\tau)d\tau$$

Applying Eq. 1 on $v_p(t)$,
$$\dot{v_p}(t)+2\lambda v_p(t)=r(t)$$
$$-2\lambda\int_{0}^{t}e^{-2\lambda (t-\tau)}r(\tau)d\tau + 2\lambda\int_{0}^{t}e^{-2\lambda (t-\tau)}r(\tau)d\tau=r(t)$$
$$0 = r(t)$$ which is a contradiction. Why is this so?

Comment: can you prove equation 2.seems to me that convolution is symmetric and that time derivative should similarly be symmetric

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177239/derivative-of-convolution/1998393

Comment: so d/dx of (f*g) = (df/dx)*g = f*(dg/dx)?

Comment: Yes, that is the theorem.

Comment: Your question would be more legible if you wrote $\dot{v}(t)$ rather than $\dot{v(t)}$.  Do you see the difference?  (I corrected it, and am waiting for moderator's approval.)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with your suggestion implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you mean $f(t)=e^{-2\lambda t}$ and $g(t)=r(t)$.

The formula for the derivative of the convolution is incorrect. By Leibniz's rule
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^tf(t-s)\,g(s)\,ds&=f(0)\,g(t)+\int_0^tf'(t-s)\,g(s)\,ds\\
&=f(0)g(t)+(f'\ast g)(t).
\end{align}
The formula $(f\ast g)'=f'\ast g$ holds when the convolution is defined as
$$
f\ast g(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t-s)\,g(s)\,ds
$$
and certain conditions on $f$ and $g$ are met.

Comment: You're right about $f(t)$ and $g(t)$. Thank you for noticing my typo; I already fixed the question. Thank you for your answer.